# Extract PDF Highlights with PDFKit

Tags: swift, cocoa, pdfkit

I'm trying to extract all Highlights using PDFkit in a macOS app. Here's the code I'm using:

```
guard let path = item.filePath else { return }

let document = PDFDocument(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))

guard let numberOfPage = document?.pageCount else { return }

for i in 0...numberOfPage - 1 {
   let pages = document?.page(at: i)
   guard let annotations = pages?.annotations else { continue }

   for annotation in annotations {
      if annotation.type == "Highlight" {
        print(annotation.contents)
        self.annotations.append(annotation)
      }
   }
}
```

The problem is that `print(annotation.contents)` always return "Optional("")". I tried several pdf, and the result is always the same. The thing is that if I do `print(annotation.color)`, it return the correct color of the given highlights.

Is there something wrong with my code that I didn't figure out? Or is this a normal behavior of PDFKit?

Comment: I don't know much about PDFKit, but that `"Highlight"` looks suspicious. Maybe using `PDFAnnotationSubtype.highlight` helps?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, `annotation.type` is a String, and `PDFAnnotationSubtype.highlight` is not. Thanks for the try anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `PDFAnnotationSubtype.highlight.rawValue` to get the key for the highlights. If you print that value, you will see that it's `/Highlight`. Even though we know the key now, you should still use the enum value, in case anything ever changes in `PDFKit`.

[image]

So in your case...

```
if annotation.type == PDFAnnotationSubtype.highlight.rawValue {
```

If that confuses you, familiarize yourself with [Enums and Raw Values.](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html#ID149)

Comment: I already tried, but it's not working. if I put a `print` in it, it's never called. I only get a return when I use `annotation.type == "Highlight"`. I tried to add a note to the PDF and by using  `annotation.type == "Popup"` and after `print(annotation.contents)`, it returns a string with the content of the note. So it seems there is only a problem with highlights...

Comment: @Herlid As the first statement inside your `for`-loop, put the following code:
`print(annotation.type.rawValue)`. What do you see?

Comment: I see an error thrown by Xcode "Value of type 'String?' has no member 'rawValue'", because `annotation.type` is a String.

Comment: Sure, sorry. Then please try it with `print(annotation.type)`.

Comment: I already checked that, the output is "Optional("Highlight")". This was how I determined that I should use `annotation.type == "Highlight"` to only extract this type.